# When I installed Unity, this window Requires me to register

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem installing Unity. When I installed Unity, this window popped up. Requires me to register. But the problem is that the buttons are not pressed. Please tell me what to do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWaeJ.png)

Sorry for my English

Comment: You need to register. I don't know what `the buttons are not pressed` means, maybe try writing a more detailed description and running it through translate.google.com

Comment: You could create an account on the unity site so it logs you in. Then hub can sort the personal license